# get aol contacts using oauth api

Tags: oauth, hotmail, aol

If there is aol api for oauth is available.

What i want is to import aol contacts using oauth. I got such a api of google, yahoo & hotmail.

Hotmail gives me email hashes instead of email ids. So ,i also ask question that if there is some way to get email id using oauth is available for hotmail.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

No, AOL doesn't have a generally available OAuth API. I have searched, but been unable to find an OAuth API for AOL contacts. AOL had a 'coming soon' page on their Contacts API since 2008, but it seems to have disappeared now.

To answer your second question: 
Microsoft has changed their policies surrounding the email addresses that you entered in your contact list. They no longer belong to you so it's not your right to share them anymore.  You can use CloudSponge to [import contacts](http://www.cloudsponge.com), including email addresses, from Windows Live. We support a delegated authentication import currently and we fall back to a CSV import method.

Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.

Answer (score 1):

To Import email address of friends from Hotmail we need to add the scope as     "wl.contacts_emails".

I am posting the complete code for it

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    WL.init({ client_id: **WRITE YOUR CLIENTID HERE**,
 redirect_uri: **place ur redirect page url** });

    WL.login({ scope: "wl.contacts_emails" }).then(
    function(response) {
        getContacts();
    },
    function(response) {
        log("Could not connect, status = " + response.status);
    }
);

function getContacts() {
    WL.api({ path: "/me/contacts", method: "GET" }).then(
        onGetContacts,
        function(response) {
            log("Cannot get contacts: " + JSON.stringify(response.error).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
        }
    );
}

function onGetContacts(response) {
    var items = response.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i > items.length) {
            break;
        }

        getContactProperties(items[i].id);
    }
 }

function getContactProperties(contactId) {
    WL.api({ path: contactId, method: "GET" }).then(onGetContactProperties);
}

function onGetContactProperties(response) {
    log(JSON.stringify(response).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
}

function log(message) {
    var child = document.createTextNode(message);
    var parent = document.getElementById('JsOutputDiv') || document.body;
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to AOL's OAuth user experience through CloudSponge.

Try it for yourself here:
http://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive

While you're there, check out our Hotmail integration (no hashes!)

...works like a charm!

Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.